# keep file upload control file path in the control!

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

i have a file upload control for uploading excel file into SQL Server base on the worksheet. After each upload completion, the file path will be cleared from the control, i wanna keep the file path in the control so user don't need to browse for the file again for different worksheet. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

You can't set the text of the upload control on the client-side for security reasons. If you could set it, it would mean you can effectively upload any file from the client machine without user interaction. Which would be bad :)